# Open particular object from button or menu

Tags: odoo

How can one open a particular object when pressing on a menu item or a button? It's useful if you want to have a sort a configuration-like object (only one object is needed to hold data e.g. username and password).

I've tried playing with `view_init` method and `active_id` context key, but with no luck. Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and found a solution : 
in your `ir.actions.act_window` definition (in XML), try to add the `res_id` field with the id of your record you want to show. If this is id is calculated, perhaps you can use the "eval" attribute of the same field to get it.

For example :

```
<field name="res_id">5</field>
```

Or (i don't know if it works)

```
<field name="res_id" eval="your_func_getting_res_id"/>
```

Of course for 2nd method, don't forget to define your function.

It works for me when i wanted to return an `ir.actions.act_window` in a method called by a button (method defined in python, so i got easily the id i wanted).

Hope it helps you or someone else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create views(tree, form, search etc) for your model. Then create action for the model for example

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="my_unique_action_id">
    <field name="name">Name for the Action</field>
    <field name="res_model">your_model_name</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">here_provide_your_domain_conditon_as list_of_tuples</field>
    <field name="context">here_provide_your_context_as_a_dictionary</field>
</record>
```

Then create a menu with action= your action id. For example

```
<menuitem action="my_unique_action_id" id="my_unique_menu_id" parent="your parent_menu_id"/>
```

If parent menu is in another module then provide `parent=the_other_module_name.parent_menu_id`

Note: I have said unique_action_id_name and unique_menu_id_name in the sense that the id should be unique in that module. Same action id can have in different module.